# How to get duplicate rows inclusive of first row number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have written below query to retrieve duplicate customers using Row_Number() in SQL Server.

```
 Cust_PKID ---------------+ CustomerID ----------------- + MobileNo
 1                        | A00001                       | 9000477444   
 2                        | A00002                       | 9000477444
 3                        | A00003                       | 9000477444
```

**Query:-**

```
Select TMP.CustID
From
(
   Select CustomerID CustID,
       Row_Number() Over(Partition By MobileNo Order By (Select Null)) As RowNo
   From dbo.Customers
) TMP
Where TMP.RowNo > 1
```

**Output:-**

```
Cust_PKID ---------------+ CustomerID ----------------- + MobileNo    
2                        | A00002                       | 9000477444
3                        | A00003                       | 9000477444
```

How can I retrieve records including of first RowNo record in single select statement?

Comment: single select not possible, you have to use function/subquery and in it always select statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `COUNT() OVER()` window function not `ROW_NUMBER`

```
Select TMP.CustID
From
(
   Select CustomerID CustID,
       COUNT(1) Over(Partition By MobileNo) As RowNo
   From dbo.Customers
) TMP
Where TMP.RowNo > 1
```

This will bring all the duplicate `MobileNo` records

Comment: Above query takes more time to execute. Nearly 10 million records are there in the customers table. I have created appropriate indexes for that table. Previously I have used Group By with Having Count(*) query. It also takes more time to execute.

Comment: ON which column you have index. Is it is used ?

Comment: I have indexes on MobileNo, CustomerID in the Customers table.

Comment: @RGS - Am not good at index things but give me some more info like is it non clustered or clustered ? or Do you have separate index for both the columns ?

Comment: Both are separate Non Clustered Indexes. I will investigate execution plan. Thank you.

Comment: @RGS - I don't think index will be usefull since it has to scan all the records i will also try my side